# Formatting time in Python?

Tags: python, formatting

How would I go about formatting time in Python?

Lets say I have

```
time = 9.122491
```

The time is in hours and I need to convert it to h:m format. So the desired output should be:

```
9:07
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @SethMMorton I don't think the strptime can deal with minutes as fractions of an hour (unless I really can't read)

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> mytime = 9.122491
>>> temp = timedelta(hours=mytime)
>>> print((datetime(1, 1, 1) + temp).strftime('%H:%M'))
09:07
```

Comment: Why you need to add `datetime(1,1,1)` to `temp`?

Comment: @naitoon To make it a datetime object. `strftime` is a function for the datetime class, not for a `timedelta`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a module, you can do it fairly simply like this:

```
>>> t = 9.122491
>>> print '%d:%02d' % ( int(t), t%int(t)*60 )
9:07
```

---

`%02d` formats numbers to have leading zeros if they're less then 2 digits long

`t%int(t)` effectively gets rid of whole digits (11.111 becomes .111), then `*60` converts the decimal fraction to minutes